# Parabolic PDEs: is it possible to simulate blow-up phenomena in MATLAB?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, matlab, parabolic-pde

I want to learn to use matlab to study the graphical behavior of parabolic partial differential equation solutions, in the sense of trying to simulate when the solution will be global or when it will blow-up. I have several questions, forgive me for the layman's questions if that's the case. For example, if I have the PDE

$  \begin{equation}\label{Fujita}
  \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{rll}
   u_t -  \Delta u &= u^{p}& \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \times (0,T), \\ 
   {u}(0) &=  {u}_{0}& \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \\
  \end{array}
  \right.
 \end{equation}$

it is known that for $p<1+\dfrac{2}{n}$ the solution blow-up in finite time(in the sense $\lim_{t \rightarrow T_{max}}||u(t)||_{\infty} = \infty$), and for $p>1+\dfrac{2}{n}$ exists a global solution. Is it possible to simulate this in MATLAB? I believe he cannot do it in unlimited domains, but is it possible to do something?

Another question, in the case of the solution to the equation above, I have a classic solution to the problem. But for example, if instead of $u^p$ I had $|x|^{\gamma}u^p$, with $\gamma<0$ there is no classical solution, only Mild Solutions, what are solutions of the integral equation
$$ \begin{equation}\label{mild-sol}
   \mathcal{F}u(t) = S(t)u_0 + \int_{0}^{t} S(t-s)|x|^{\gamma}u^p(s) ds
  \end{equation}$$

Here for every $t > 0$, $S(t)$ denotes the heat semigroup
$$[S(t)f](x) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} K(x,y;t)f(y)dy,$$
where $K(x,y,t)$ is the heat Kernel of heat defined by
$$K(x,y;t) = (4\pi t)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{|x^2|}{4t}}, \quad t >0, \quad x\in \mathbb{R}^n.$$
Question: Is there a way to simulate the behavior Mild solution in MatLab? Is there any numerical formulation?

Thanks for any clarifications or suggestions for books to study, as I'm really at a loss to know what can and can't be done with the software.

Comment: If you know how to solve PDEs in Matlab, the answer to your first question is a straightforward `yes'. So given the formulation of your question, you are maybe asking 'how do I solve a PDE in matlab in the first place?' Or did you already try something that did not work?

Comment: I'm still learning, now I miss good, objective and clear study materials. I asked the question above, because I haven't found anything related yet, so I wanted to know if there's a way to do it or not.

Comment: If you do not have much experience solving PDEs in Matlab, I would then just use the build-in PDE solver https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html, and then you can study the blow-up by increasing the time interval. This is of course not rigorous, but it gives you an idea.

Comment: Maybe I should read your question in another way: Can I give Matlab a PDE and can Matlab automatically decide if there is finite time blow-up or not? In that case, I'm inclined to say 'no, matlab has no such feature'.